# codeigniter counting rows in the view

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my view I'm trying to count the number of rows. depending on the count i want to leave out last three rows and show the remaining in my view
My controller:

```
          $data['info'] = $this->TrainingEvaluationModel->getQ();

      $this->load->view('TrainingEvaluationView', $data);
```

My Model from where the data is coming is shown:

```
         function getQ() {
           $sql = $this->db->get('training_evaluation_entry');
return $sql->result();

}
```

My view is given below:

```
<?php
foreach ($info as $row){ 
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    $i=$row->id;
    echo "<div class='firstc'>".$row->id ."</div>";    
    echo "<div class='secondc'>".$row->name ."</div>";
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="training_evaluation_entry_id'.$i.'" value='.$i.'>';
    echo '<input type= "radio" name="group'.$i.'" value="strongly agreed"> Strongly Agreed';
    echo '<input  type= "radio" name="group'.$i.'" value="agreed"> Agreed';
    echo '<input  type= "radio" name="group'.$i.'" value="neutral">neutral';
    echo '<input  type= "radio" name="group'.$i.'" value="disagree">disagree';
    echo '<input  type= "radio" name="group'.$i.'" value="strongly disagree">strongly disagree';
    echo "</div>";
}
?> 
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

how can i leave out the last three rows from showing?? i am using codeigniter. please help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to see how many rows you have, and [`array_splice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) to drop the last 3 items before you start your loop:

```
if (count($info) > 10) {
    array_splice($info, -3);
}
foreach ($info as $row) {
    ...
```

You didn't specify what rules you actually wanted to follow depending on the count. The above code will drop the last three items if we're starting with more than 10 items - it should be easy to adapt to the exact rules you need.

Comment: The 1st 10 rows will go to a rodio button option and the remaining will go to a textbox. i've tried with your suggestion but it's not working.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "go to a rodio button" or "go to a textbox". Please edit your question to provide more details about exactly what you want to happen.

Comment: my controller and model has been added